# Recursively searching for specific text inside specific files but only in specific folders

Tags: linux, coreutils

I have a nested folder structure containing lots of folders and files.

How do I search inside files for a pattern eg "sampletext", but only if the filename matches a pattern (eg only search inside files with .txt extension) and finally the containing folder name must match another pattern? (eg "data").

I'm sure I could write a shell script to do it, but I'm sure clever one-liners exist that will teach me new things!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you have a nested folder structure, I believe `*data*/*txt` won’t do what you need.  I suggest

```
find . –type d –name "*data*" –exec sh –c "grep sampletext /dev/null {}/*.txt" \;
```

The `/dev/null` is there to force `grep` to display the filename even when it runs on a directory that has only one `.txt` file in it.